# How does the Python Syntax "ARRAY + [ITEM]" work?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given this code:

```
array = [1,2,3]
temp = []

for i in array:
   new = temp + [i]

print new
```

The result is **[3]**

I don't understand why the result is only **3** not **[1,2,3]**

Sorry if this is a trivial question for some.

Comment: No the result is `[3]`. Because you do not do anything with `new`: so when the second iteration takes place, `new` is set to `temp + [2]` and so on. Only the *last* iteration decides what `new` is.

Comment: `temp` is always `[]`. You never assign anything else to `temp`. What, then, is `temp + [i]` on the last iteration?

Comment: I think you want to change `new = temp + [i]` to `temp.append(i)` and you'll get your expected output. And then change `print new` to `print temp`.